# ffmpeg: Could not find tag for codec none in stream #2

Tags: ffmpeg

To add a second audio track to a video having already one audio, I tried

```
$ ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.m4a -map 0   -map 1:a -c:v copy -shortest __out.mp4
Could not find tag for codec none in stream #2, codec not currently supported in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69524678/), I added the -v option:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.m4a -map 0 -map 1:av -c:v copy -shortest __out.mp4
Stream map '1:v' matches no streams.
```

The file 2.m4a has the correct audio. How to fix this?

Comment: I'd suggest add the full ffmpeg log to the post for both runs to give us a better idea. But, it appears that the second file is corrupt (or using an esoteric codec) based on the first message.

Comment: Here is the full ffmpeg-output and MediaInfo for both files: https://notebin.de/?08961c7e07bcf19e#Dh1ULvoFDKKpWgbd8abYXJ5R2msVLHnVDouydETqKa5a

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try to just copy everything?

[edit] Also, see if removing timecode data stream (#0:2) from the first file:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.m4a -map 0 -map -0:2 -map 1:a -c copy -shortest __out.mp4
```

Comment: `$ ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.m4a -map 0 -map 1:a -c copy -shortest __out.mp4
[mp4 @ 0x562631347d40] You requested a copy of the original timecode track so timecode metadata are now ignored
[mp4 @ 0x562631347d40] Could not find tag for codec none in stream #2, codec not currently supported in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:3 -- 
Stream mapping:
 Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
 Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
 Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (copy)
 Stream #1:0 -> #0:3 (copy)
  Last message repeated 1 times`

Comment: What happens if you try `ffmpeg -i 2.m4a -map 0:a -c copy __out.m4a`?

Comment: It provides the file without video and correct audio, same file size as the 2.m2a which I created using ´ffmpeg -i 2.mp4 -vn -acodec copy 2.m4a`

Comment: So, it's not the second file. My next guess is that the timecode stream (#0:2) is the culprit. See if not mapping it to the output makes a difference (see my post body).

Answer (score 0):

Yes we think the issue is #0:20x3 and solved it like this:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -i inAudio.m4a -map 0 -c:v copy -map 1:a:0 -c:a copy -dn _new.mp4
```